# LWC - Push New Values to Object Array in JS for use in Lightning Web Components

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I just want to push new values to existing object arrays I pull using Apex but when I compile and run what I have below it simply doesn't work. This sounds like a very basic problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

I simply need to pass these new objects/values

> isAmount
>
> isPercent

for each of my array list. These new values will be used later on conditional DOM rendering.

Please see a snippet of my code below:

**JS**

```
    getAccounts({ opptyId : this.recordId})
    .then(result => {
          this.record = result;
          for(let i = 0; i < this.record.length; i++) {

              if(this.record[i].DiscountType__c === 'Percent'){
                  this.record[i].push({isPercent : true, isAmount : false}); // Doesn't work ...
              }
              if(this.record[i].DiscountType__c === 'Amount'){
                  this.record[i].push({isAmount : true, isPercent : false}); // Doesn't work ...
              }

              this.myList = this.record;
              this.error = undefined;
          })
    .catch(error => {
          this.error = error;
          this.record = undefined;
    });
    }
```

I've also tried the following, but to no avail.

```
this.record.push({isPercent : true, isAmount : false}); // Just creates a new line of array

this.record.push({Id: this.record[i].Id, isPercent : true, isAmount : false}); // Creates a new line of array but with the same Id from an existing one
```

How do I correctly do this - and is there a better way?

I would appreciate help and suggestions on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `<lightning-data-table>` and the `<lightning-tree-grid>` are both suffering from this issue when pushing a new item in the doesn't re-render the component. Are you using the `myList` property with one of those components or with a different component?

Comment: I'm actually using a Custom Data Table to which, when given the right attributes, myList successfully re-renders. @pmdartus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is not push, but map:

```
this.record = result;
this.myList = this.record.map(row => ({
  ...row,
  isPercent: row.DiscountType__c==='Percent',
  isAmount: row.DiscountType__c==='Amount'
}));
```

This transforms the row by appending two new attributes.

The ... operator copies all the existing properties, while the other two lines add two new calculated properties.

Comment: Excellent, I just tried it and it works! With fewer lines of code as well. Thanks, @sfdcfox.